# Creating a nested array with unspecified number of columns

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create a nested array that takes the user's input and stores it in the sub arrays. The number of subarrays is given by the user. I need the columns to be unspecified, and any number of elements can go in.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I tried:

```
puts "How many groups do you want to create?"
number_of_teams = gets.chomp
team_array = [Array.new(number_of_teams.to_i){Array.new()}]
```

Comment: Better to write `number_of_teams = gets.to_i`, as you need an integer, not a string. There's no need for `chomp` with `to_i`: `"21\n".to_i #=> 21`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`team_array = Array.new(number_of_teams.to_i) { [] }`

So if input is 3 then `team_array` will have  `[ [], [], [] ]`

Comment: thanks, and then the sub arrays can take however many elements that is needed at the time?

Comment: You can add as many as you want e.g 
`team_array[0] << 'hello'`
`team_array[0] << 'world'`
will add two elements in first sub array. And it will be like this `[ ["hello", "world"], [], [] ] `

Comment: As an extension to this, I need to add a users input into each sub array. For example, if the user inputs Mary, John and Joseph the team_array would look like `[ ["Mary"] , ["John"], ["Joseph"] ]`

MY code is:

`puts "Enter a name:"
 while name = gets.chomp
  if name == "stop"
    break
  else puts "Enter a name:"
    team_array << name    
  end
end`

But this just adds each name to the first sub array, how can I add each consecutive name to the next sub array?

Comment: ```puts "How many groups do you want to create?"
team_array = []
input = gets.chomp
while input != 'stop'
  team_array << input
  input = gets.chomp
end

puts team_array
```

Answer (score 0):

This is true for **any** Array. Ruby doesn't have the concept of an Array of a fixed number of elements. You don't even need to ask the user for the number of groups.